# How to display values of two different task register variables in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Below is my playbook,

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: asyn task 1 use time command to see diff use when hostname to get faster output
    command: sleep 15
    async: 2
    poll: 0
    register: result1

  - name: asyn task
    command: sleep 2
    register: result2

  - name: showing result1
    debug:
     var: result1
     var1: result2

  - name: debugging output
    debug: msg=this is the {‌{ result1 }} and {‌{ result2 }}
#   with_items:
#   - {‌{ result1 }}
#   - {‌{ result2 }}
```

getting below error,

```
changed: [vishwa]



TASK [showing result1] **************************************************************************************************

fatal: [rudra]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "'var1' is not a valid option in debug"}

fatal: [arya]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "'var1' is not a valid option in debug"}

fatal: [vishwa]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "'var1' is not a valid option in debug"}

        to retry, use: --limit @/home/admin/ansibledemo/asynch.retry
```

Answer (score 0):

First point, [`debug`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html) module doesn't have an option `var1` and so the error from `showing result1` task. You probably have figured that out and written `debugging output` task with `msg` option.

This brings to the second point, registering status of an asynchronous task. Since you are using `poll: 0`, the task would be executing in asynchronous mode so the result may not be immediately available to the registered variable. Use [`async_status`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/async_status_module.html) to check the result as described [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#concurrent-tasks-poll-0). Also, in your scenario you should use `async` value more than `sleep` period.

An example,

```yaml
- name: Wait for asynchronous job to end
  async_status:
    jid: '{{ result1.ansible_job_id }}'
  register: job_result
  until: job_result.finished
  retries: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe below playbook file could help you to fulfill your requirement. If not then I have some other alternatives too.

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  name: "[ Debug Senario Test ]"
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
          - name: "[[ Command Task 1 ]]"
            command: "echo Command Task 1"
            register: register1
          - name: "[[ Command Task 2 ]]"
            command: "echo Command Task 2"
            register: register2
          - name: "[[ Display Registers ]]"
            command: "echo {{ item.stdout }}"
            with_items:
                    - "{{ register1 }}"
                    - "{{register2}}"
            register: register3
          - debug:
                  msg: "{{ register3 }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. debug does not have a parameter var1, or var. You can't just create a parameter for a module. The error message is clear.
2. If you would like to store the result1 or result2 then use set_fact module.
3. You are executing a task in async running in the background. Async task follows a fire and forget execution. That task will be triggered and in running state while the other is being triggered. Use 2 https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/async_status_module.html
   for fetching the result of the async task.

Ref:https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_async.html